# What's "less" in nevertheless and nonetheless?

Tags: etymology

*OED*'s webpage on [nevertheless](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/126496?redirectedFrom=nevertheless#eid) defines it as

> Notwithstanding; despite that; nonetheless; all the same.

But it and the webpage on [nonetheless](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/127938?redirectedFrom=nonetheless#eid) don't expound the etymologies. I already grasp, and I'm not asking about, their meanings.

1. Rather, how exactly did never/none + the + less compound to mean what they do?
2. Particularly, is ["less"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/less) here an adverb, pronoun, or determiner?
3. What does "less" refer to? What's "less" than what?

   [Nevertheless « The Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2012/04/nevertheless/)

> The key to “nonetheless,” “nevertheless” and “notwithstanding” is that they all require and refer to an antecedent statement, which may or may not be referred to elsewhere in the sentence. “Nonetheless” “notwithstanding” and “nevertheless” mean that what has been said or known (call it “X”) does not prevent, diminish or invalidate, etc., the fact that the primary statement “Y” is true, valid, etc. (“Limo services Los Angeles have been in demand for years. Nonetheless, their business is fairly limited…,” 10/01/11). The first statement makes the second “none the less” (or “never the less”) true.

[nevertheless (adv.)](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=nevertheless)

> "notwithstanding," early 14c., neuer þe lesse; as one word from mid-14c., neuerþeles. The sense of never here is "not at all; none the," as in unmerged expressions such as never the wiser, never the worse. In the same sense Middle English also had never-less (early 14c.),  neverthelater (c. 1200), never-later (late 14c.).

[nonetheless | Search Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=nonetheless)

> "not the more or not the less on that account," 1839, none the less; contracted into one word by c. 1930.

Comment: Insomuch as they can be paraphrased at this point at all (they, like any idiom, now has a set meaning that may not be possible to fully parse according to their individual words), I would paraphrase them as "to no lesser degree." I also disagree with the summary from The Word Detective. In many cases, the referent of the words is what immediately *follows* them, not what preceded them: *You may find it strange; **nevertheless**, it's true.* In that sentence, it's a fact that the truth value is not diminished—despite your impression of it. (And the pronoun refers to something that came before.)

Answer (score 3):

This may be simplistic, but surely nonetheless, nevertheless, notwithstanding (all adverbial conjunctions, I think) imply that the statement that is to follow (that which is about to be conjoined) is not any less true or of lesser value than the statement that precedes it (that which it is conjoined to by the conjunction). re Question #2, I don't think it's possible to break a word apart and track the etymology or function of that part in isolation. That leaves your Question 1, so far, unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

OED

> **Less.**
>
> II. Noun uses, as a comparative corresponding to little pron. and n. III.
>
> 3.a. With the. That which is smaller or less important (of two things compared). Now somewhat rare.
>
> 1956   E. S. Duckett Alfred the Great ix. 175   *All, therefore, writes Alfred, is of God, the greater and the less: the sun and the little stars..; the tiny brook which runs to meet the river and the river winding toward the sea.*

Non/none – a negative

Nonetheless – not being smaller /lesser / of lesser importance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer, but a notable tangent in German *desto* as in *nichts desto weniger* "nonetheless" and *nichtsdestotrotz* "despite".

Ger. *desto* is cognate with Engl. *the*, specificly Old English *þæsþe*, from genitive+instrumentalis. It's used as conjunction in comparisons.

I find notable overall how particles like articles are used in comparisons, e.g. in the superlative "the biggest", likewise in French "le plus grand", also "the more the merrier", etc. p. p. The latter is indeed from *þæsþe* if I understand correctly (en. wiktionary, DWDS). Compare this with the German "Desto mehr desto besser" (which is however uncommon, rather *je mehr desto besser, um so mehr...*), and similar to Engl. *so far so good*. Note that *so* was in one paradigm with *the*, ultimately from Proto-Indo-European *so ~ *to.

The match between these phrases is not exact, none the least because *none* and *nicht* aren't directly cognate (unless through French *non* "no"). Whereas *ne-* "negating particle" + *ein* "an, 1" gives *nein* "no!" in German, we use *kein* "none, no", and that even in some idiomatic comparatives, e.g. *kein schöner Land* "no better land". Arguably the determiner already serves a similar role as the definitive article would to establish the *absolute* fact of comparison.

The genitive comes into play with the negation. First you have to consider that constructs like *a man of small hight* has no good reason to use "of" or, coralary, the genitive in German (*groß-er Statur, der größten Statur*). Moreover, we see that *one, none* (*kein*) etc. can be interpreted as pronouns. So posit e.g. *there were none of a greater hight*, in which case *none* is clearly a personal pronoun. In pragmatic discours, we might personify arguments, too, even if the argument is literally nothing. In this view, the phrase *none the less* is grammatically ambiguous, as either part could stem from a noun phrase: Where we might say *She said nothing else*, I would consider if *She said none the less* hadn't worked as well.

Another topic here is nominalization of adjectives with *-er*, which might be ambiguous with the comparative--not anymore in English. Meyer-Brügge (textbook: F 323)  argues that adjectives came to Proto-Indo-European from "appositven Nomina", quoting Irene Balles to the effect that the underspecified difference between noun and adjective was not lexical, merely a syntactic one.

That said, to sum up your questions:

> 1. Rather, how exactly did never/none + the + less compound to mean what they do?

We speak of fossilization. You say you know what they mean, but since they are cinjunctiins, it's more important to know how to use them. The glosses quited from the OED certainly don't explain that. Conjunctions tend to be less than stable, so the fossilization probably happened rather late. The original was probably transparent, but became ambiguius through idiomatic usage (compare *could care less*). I pointed out that it must have been a form of comparison initially. Beyond that, we should look at quotes from the OED, if you can find any.

> 2. Particularly, is "less" here an adverb, pronoun, or determiner?

If *nonetheless* is concieved of as one word, then it makes hardly any sense to ask for the POS of its compounds. I tried to argue that it was ambiguous and that it is again underspecified, now. The whole phrase is a conjunction or adverb. So are its constituents, if you will.

> 3. What does "less" refer to? What's "less" than what?

In my above (re) construction treating it as an adjective, it refers to the aforesaid, simply the next possible referent. If none is available, it can be interpreted as rhethorical question. Out of context it cannot be interpreted. *Mike is bigger* - - bigger than who? In that sense, also compare *unless, lest*.

More interestingly, if taking *the less* as a noun, then *none* is its coreferent. *Mike the great*. In this sense it's almost an interjection. *Jimminy Cricket, I have no idea*.

Nevertheless, as I said initially, all that is just tangential information.